# TypeScript: Make sure all the fields in interface are nullable

Tags: typescript

Does anybody know, is it possible in TypeScript to make type constraints, which will check that all the fields in an interface have `null` in types. Let's say, I need to create a general validation function, which will replace by null all the false values.
Please check the example below. Object, which implements the interface `y` shouldn't be sent to the `validate` function because of `field2`.

```
interface y {
    field1: number | null;
    field2: string;
}

function validate<T>(obj: T) {
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((key) => {
        obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] : null;
    });
}

const obj: y = {
    field1: 3,
    field2: 'x'
}

validate(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic type to validate `T` using a self-referencing constraint:

```
type AllNullable<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: null extends T[K] ? T[K] : never;
};

function validate<T extends AllNullable<T>>(obj: T) {
    (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>).forEach((key) => {
        obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] : null; // uh oh
    });
}
```

but this causes an error in the body since TypeScript doesn't understand that `obj[key]` must include `null` in its type. There are many ways to get around this:

```
//@ts-ignore
obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] : null;
```

```
obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] : null!;
```

```
obj[key] = obj[key] ? obj[key] : null as T[keyof T];
```

Now let's test it:

```
interface x {
    prop1: boolean | null;
    prop2: number | null;
}

interface y {
    field1: number | null;
    field2: string;
}

validate({} as x); // passing a 'x' is ok
validate({} as y); // passing a 'y' is not
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgB7IN4FgBQz-IAOUA9oQIwBcyARiSQDYRwjIA+yIArgwwNy4CRUoQBM1bgFsa0dpx79cAX1y5QkWIhQBPTIIIxgEBgBMq86bI7deAvAaOnxyAM5gooAOZ2VOXGG1CFABBXgA5BTgaJgAeABUAPmQAXj17fABtAGlkUGQAawhtEhhkOIBdCQVkCFRIEBMXMuzy5AB+ZqzWiQgAN2gfO1wYLhAEMGASVl64BmATOEh4mrqIBqbQhgjeKNjEhIAKEhoAK2o4gEo0oQOAeVOIcYA6Qu0XI9OruA2oKDhtGKvEplBIXJ4wEhQACiiAAFgcDq8rskkth0kJkMcThlXq1UlicUVWh0CbjkFVeABCOxCJQXHyqHAzOYLSAHDBKZDfND05AAej5RG+Li8XOQAHJUOLck0SPlcMz5osIOzOdztLyBUKXCKQJ4xeLtNLgE0QCQwLggA)